# Where to place resources, e.g. images, that scaladoc can use?

Tags: sbt, scaladoc

I am currently writing the documentation of an API written in Scala. I would like to include several diagrams to make the code more understandable.

I am wondering where to put resources (such as diagrams) in order that they can be automatically imported by an invocation of scaladoc, and how to refer to these resources in the documentation of the code.

For example, let's assume that I use sbt. My code is located in the `src/main/scala` directory. Here is an example of a scala package object for package `foo`:

```
/**
 * Provides main classes of the bar API.
 *
 * ==Overview==
 * Main classes are depicted on the following diagram:
 * <img src="path/to/diagram-foo.svg" />
 *
 */
package object foo {
}
```

Where should 'diagram-foo.svg' be located in my project in order to be visible to scaladoc? Subsequently, what is the correct value of `path/to/` in the `img` tag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**WARNING** It may be a hack as I know very little about scaladoc.

Since `<img src="../path/to/diagram-foo.svg" />` is just a regular HTML you just need to copy necessary assets to the doc target path so the `img` resolves.

You can use the following `copyDocAssetsTask` custom task that with `(doc in Compile)` and `src/main/doc-resources` directory gives you what you want. The point is to copy images to the directory where the documentation is generated, i.e. `(target in (Compile, doc)).value`.

**build.sbt**:

```
lazy val copyDocAssetsTask = taskKey[Unit]("Copy doc assets")

copyDocAssetsTask := {
  println("Copying doc assets")
  val sourceDir = file("src/main/doc-resources")
  val targetDir = (target in (Compile, doc)).value
  IO.copyDirectory(sourceDir, targetDir)
}

copyDocAssetsTask <<= copyDocAssetsTask triggeredBy (doc in Compile)
```

Obviously the directory where you place the images is arbitrary, and when you decide otherwise, just update the custom task accordingly.

Comment: This works, even though not built-in with scaladoc. Thank you!

Comment: Great! We're both learning sbt! Please accept the answer when time permits. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, I used an adaptation of this that I hope might help others, particularly on multi-module projects:

First, unidoc at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-unidoc will merge your scaladoc from multi-module projects into a single location, which is typically what you want. Then the following in build.sbt:

```
lazy val copyDocAssetsTask = taskKey[Unit]("Copy unidoc resources")

copyDocAssetsTask := {
  println("Copying unidoc resources")
  val sourceDir = file("src/main/doc-resources")
  val targetDir = (target in (Compile, doc)).value.getParentFile
  println(s"from ${sourceDir.getAbsolutePath} to ${targetDir.getAbsolutePath}")
  IO.copyDirectory(sourceDir, new java.io.File(targetDir, "unidoc"))
}

copyDocAssetsTask := (copyDocAssetsTask triggeredBy (unidoc in Compile)).value
```

then put your documents under `src/main/doc-resources` *in the root project* in subdirectories following your package structure for the path to your class with the scaladoc to include the diagram (this just saves you having to mess around with parent directories in the URL) and embed something like:

`<img src="DesignModel.svg" width="98%"/>` in your scaladoc

e.g. if this scaladoc was in a class in package `com.someone.thing` in any project in the multi-module build, the `DesignModel.svg` file would go in `src/main/doc-resources/com/someone/thing` inside the root project.